# How does class Collections turn a list/set to a synchronized object? Through what mechanism?

Tags: java, collections, synchronized

So I know how to call a static method in the Collections class to make a list, which was created before, to become synchronized. But I am wondering, how does one achieve that?

There are 2 ways to make an object synchronized that I know (synchronized methods and blocks), but it does not seem to be the case in how Collections does it, which turns an "existing" object into a synchronized one. Any ideas?

Comment: Source code is here. It's a bit involved, but you can easily see that it's a wrapper class around the original list instance. http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/jdk8-b132/src/share/classes/java/util/Collections.java#l2410

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Collections.synchronizedList()` doesn't return the original list. It returns a new instance of List which wraps the original list and delegates to it for all the List methods, i.e. a proxy.

This proxy has methods such as

```
@Override
public synchronized T get(int index) {
    return originalList.get(index);
}
```

The source code is available, and comes with the JDK. Just look at it.